# How can I create common ViewModel for two fragments with a dagger2?

Tags: android, dagger-2, android-viewmodel

I use Single Activity Architecture in my application and I need to create a ViewModel common for two fragments using Dagger2. If I create ViewModel  for Activity Scope, it will live longer than necessary. How can i implement this smartly? Or its ok to use Activity Scope?

Answer (score 0):

From Android developers documentation, the approach to use Activity scope for sharing ViewModel between fragment is fine.

You can refer the document here [Share data between fragments](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel)